# Not getting work and institute details from the facebook account

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api

This is my code. Help me to fetch work and institute details from my facebook account. Is i am doing something wrong?

```
  if result.token != nil {

        let profileReq = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "email, first_name,last_name,id,work,education"])
        let connection = FBSDKGraphRequestConnection()
        connection.addRequest(profileReq, completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                print("Graph Request Result: \(result)")

                if let email = result.valueForKey("email") as? String {
```

//For first name

```
                    let first_name = result.valueForKey("first_name") as! String
```

//For last name

```
                    let last_name = result.valueForKey("last_name") as! String
```

//For ID

```
                    let fb_id = result.valueForKey("id") as! String
```

//For Profile Picture

```
                    let profile_pic = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + fb_id + "/picture?type=large"
```

//For work details as Array

```
                    let wrkAr = NSMutableArray()
                    if let workAr = result.objectForKey("work") as? NSArray {
                        for i in 0..<workAr.count {
                            let obj = workAr.objectAtIndex(i) as! NSDictionary

                            var name = ""
                            if let employer = obj.objectForKey("employer") as? NSDictionary {
                                name = employer.valueForKey("name") as! String
                            }

                            var pos = ""
                            if let position = obj.objectForKey("position") as? NSDictionary {
                                pos = position.valueForKey("name") as! String
                            }

                            name = name + "_" + pos + "_" + "no"

                            wrkAr.addObject(name)
                        }
                    }
```

//For Education details as Array

```
                    let eduAr = NSMutableArray()
                    if let educationAr = result.objectForKey("education") as? NSArray {
                        for i in 0..<educationAr.count {
                            let obj = educationAr.objectAtIndex(i) as! NSDictionary

                            var name = ""
                            if let school = obj.objectForKey("school") as? NSDictionary {
                                name = school.valueForKey("name") as! String
                            }

                            name = name + "_"

                            eduAr.addObject(name)
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: What the error getting?

Comment: Getting nil for while executing this result.objectForKey("work") as? NSArray

Comment: Have you check the permission into facebook settings.

Comment: open this url and check https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ you can check the result from facebook

Comment: Permissions is publlic in facebook settings.

Comment: Have you try this tool for your source data.

Comment: Thanks! it worked.

Comment: Can you please know the issue so anybody can help this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work and Education details permissions need to be [reviewed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/what-is-login-review) by Facebook before you can get those details from the user profile. As per the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions):

```
user_work_history
user_education_history
```

> If your app requests this permission Facebook will have to review how
>   your app uses it.

Basically you have to log into [developers.facebook.com](http://developers.facebook.com) and request those permissions to be reviewed by Facebook for that specific app. Facebook will review your privacy policy and terms of use before giving you their approval. Only after that you will be able to retrieve that information from your users.

I would defensively validate the incoming value though as many people leave that empty on their Facebook profiles. Make sure you are accounting for empty/undefined values for those to 2 fields.